# Universal user ID for hyperlinks to folders

Tags: links

I would like to provide a link to the WORD STARTUP folder for my colleagues.  How can I do this so that it works across all computers with different user login IDs?

Is there something I can put in the link that is universal to all users?

For example, the link is below.

What can I put in place of "[unique windows login ID]" that will allow them to simply copy and paste into the URL.  The alternative is for me to just tell them to manually enter their unique user id.

```
C:\Users\ [unique windows login] \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What can I put in place of "[unique windows login ID]"?

> that will allow them to simply copy and paste into the URL. The alternative is for me to just tell them to manually enter their unique user id

```
C:\Users\ [unique windows login] \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word
```

You can make use of `%APPDATA%`.

- `%APPDATA%` expands to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming` where `{username}` is the user name of the currently logged in user.

The examples below show you how to use `%APPDATA%`.

Notes:

- If you only need up to the user name part of the path then you can use  `%USERPROFILE%`
- `%USERPROFILE%` expands to `%SystemDrive%\Users\{username}`, where `%SystemDrive%` will usually be `C:`, and `{username}` is the user name of the currently logged in user.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) list other interesting predefined environment variables that can be used in similar situations.

---

#### To use in a hyperlink

Type `file://%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word` into a browser address bar.

- This makes use of the the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to address files on the local computer.
- Many programs will recognise `file://%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word` as a hyperlink which will open in the system default browser.

> The file URI scheme is a [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) specified in [RFC 1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630) and [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), typically used to retrieve files from within one's own computer.

Source [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

---

#### To use in a shortcut:

You can use `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word` as the link `Target`.

Example:

I don't have Word installed but to test I created a shortcut to `C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice`, and modified the shortcut properties as follows:

- Set "Target" to "%APPDATA%\LibreOffice"
- Click "OK"

[image]

The modified shortcut works as expected.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.

Comment: Thanks,  that works for shortcuts.  Anyway to imbed a similar thing into a hyperlink?

Comment: @Jamiho You can paste `file://%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word` into a browser address bar. Added to answer.

Comment: `%userprofile%` should give you `c:\users\<yourname>`...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sure but OP specifically wants the roaming profile ie `%appdata%`

Comment: @DavidPostill His example path was to AppData, but the question really only involves up to the user's name.  Anyhow, your environment variables link should cover it, that's why I just stuck it in as a comment (and up-voted). ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks, and answer expanded to take your comments into account ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to use `%username%` in the file link.  Since windows 7 at least, a link that starts `%username%` will always take you to the root of the user's account folder on their local pc.

So `C:\Users\%username%\Documents` will always take the user to their own local documents folder on the PC that they are using.  You can try this by pasting one of those url's into the address bar of your file explorer.